# jetpack compose how to move focus up on shift+tab pressed

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have two singleline TextField in a vertical Column. With the following code, keyboard focus switch from up to down when tab/enter key pressed. But shift+tab/enter press can't make focus up.

```kotlin
    val focus = LocalFocusManager.current

    TextField(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .onPreviewKeyEvent {
                if (it.key == Key.Tab || it.key == Key.Enter && it.type == KeyEventType.KeyDown) {
                    val direction =
                        if (it.isShiftPressed) FocusDirection.Up else FocusDirection.Down
                    focus.moveFocus(direction)
                    true
                } else {
                    false
                }
            }
```